# How Do I Know Which Methods to Override When Writing an Objective-C Category?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, overriding, objective-c-category

I want to write a category on `UINavigationItem` to make changes to `barBackButtonItem` across my entire app.

From what I have been told in the comments here ( [Change BackBarButtonItem for All UIViewControllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34773263/300129) ), I should "override backBarButtonItem in it, then your method will be called whenever their back bar button item is called for." - but how do I know what method to override? I have looked at the UINavigationItem documentation, and there are multiple methods used for initializing a `backBarButtonItem`. How do I determine which method I should override in my category?

Comment: You cannot override methods in a category, do you mean a subclass?

Comment: Ok that is what I thought but the person on the other post seemed confident I could override `backBarButtonItem` in a Category ... Please look here if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34773263/300129

Comment: no, he's wrong. Attempting to override a method in a category will flag a warning in Xcode and won't give you desired results. What you want to do is _subclass_ `UIViewController`, and in the `-viewDidLoad` set your `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title` to what you want.

Comment: Ok so the end point is, I have to go through each View Controller and change the title of each backBarButtonItem, correct?

Comment: No, you only need to change it in the subclass. That change will be reflected in all your view controllers provided you change their class to the subclass you made.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want a **subclass** of `UIViewController` instead of a **catagory**.

For example:

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController

@end

@implementation CustomViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"";
}

@end
```

Now you just need to use the `CustomViewController` class for your view controllers, and they will all have the changes applied to them.

If you're doing this programatically, then you'll just want to change the superclass of the view controllers:

[image]

**From this.... to this...**

[image]

If you're using storyboards, you'll want to change the superclass from within the Identity Inspector...

[image]

Comment: Thank You - How would I make this theory work with all my existing View Controllers ?

Comment: I have added screenshots showing you how to do this

Comment: Please note that class names and other global names should begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: wasn't exactly a formal example, but of course you're right. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override `backBarButtonItem`, override `backBarButtonItem`.  There is one and only one method called `backBarButtonItem`. ObjC methods are uniquely determined by their name.

You'd do it like so:

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (MyCategory)

- (UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem
{
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]
}

@end
```

I'm not saying it's a good idea, but that's how you'd do it.